# What type of lubricant should be used on PVC windows, and how often should it be applied?

Tags: windows, pvc, lubrication

As far as I know, the lifespan of PVC windows is highly dependent on periodic lubrication. What kind of oil should I use to lubricate the moving metal parts of my PVC windows? Additionally, what should be the time span between two applications of the lubricant?

Comment: Oils are bad on PVC, Silicone is good. Silicon is really bad. Silicone is bad for places that are painted, will be painted or places you want paint to stay. Because of this gelled silicone is usually much better than spray. Apply with the always popular 'lint free cloth.' Using paper towels to apply or remove silicone is bad. Using silicone lube on solid silicone is bad, anyone with silicone sex toys take note of this. application frequency is based on need, no absolute on this based only on time.

Answer (score 1):

Quality sliding PVC windows use rollers. Keep the tracks clean, using a slightly damp lint-free cloth. The rollers take care of themselves.

On cheap PVC sliders, I use paste wax after cleaning the slot with a slightly damp lint-free cloth.

You can also use spray silicone. Clean the track with a slightly damp lint-free cloth. Spray the silicone on another lint-free cloth and wipe the track down.

Don't use any petroleum lubricants on PVC if you want it to last.